# Convert character to date considering am/pm and milliseconds

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a character to date with the next format. I have the next dataframe `i` (I add `dput()` version of my dataframe at the end):

```
                     Date
1  Dec_28_2012_9:32:54:640PM
2  Dec_28_2012_9:33:07:310PM
3  Dec_28_2012_9:33:08:926PM
4  Dec_29_2012_5:51:14:626AM
5  Dec_29_2012_5:51:30:650AM
6  Dec_29_2012_5:54:22:473AM
7  Dec_29_2012_5:58:37:443AM
8  Jan_1_2012_12:03:53:123AM
9  Jan_1_2012_12:08:47:720AM
10 Jan_1_2012_12:11:39:503AM
11 Jan_1_2012_12:37:34:016PM
12 Jan_1_2012_12:37:37:440PM
13 Jan_1_2012_12:37:48:693PM
14 Jan_1_2012_12:38:29:443PM
```

How you can see the format of my date variable has a format with hour, minute, second, millisecond and am/pm. All the elements are separated with `_`. I have tried to converse to date but I got this kind of errors:

```
strptime(i$Date,format="%M_%d_%Y_%H:%m:%s")
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Maybe I am using the wrong function or something is missing inside the function. Also I don't know how to manage the am/pm in this character variable to get the date in a correct format.

The `dput()` version of my dataframe is the next:

```
i<-structure(list(Date = structure(1:14, .Label = c("Dec_28_2012_9:32:54:640PM", 
"Dec_28_2012_9:33:07:310PM", "Dec_28_2012_9:33:08:926PM", "Dec_29_2012_5:51:14:626AM", 
"Dec_29_2012_5:51:30:650AM", "Dec_29_2012_5:54:22:473AM", "Dec_29_2012_5:58:37:443AM", 
"Jan_1_2012_12:03:53:123AM", "Jan_1_2012_12:08:47:720AM", "Jan_1_2012_12:11:39:503AM", 
"Jan_1_2012_12:37:34:016PM", "Jan_1_2012_12:37:37:440PM", "Jan_1_2012_12:37:48:693PM", 
"Jan_1_2012_12:38:29:443PM"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Date", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also the `sessionInfo()` of my R session is the next:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Ecuador.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Ecuador.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Ecuador.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=Spanish_Ecuador.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] chron_2.3-45    lubridate_1.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4  memoise_0.1   plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.2   stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.0.2
```

Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Try `strptime(i$Date, "%b_%d_%Y_%I:%M:%S:%OS%p")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to fixing the date formatting string, the last colon needs to be changed to a decimal point in order for the milliseconds to parse properly (or at all). Thanks to @DavidArenburg for his comment as well.

I've created a new column in the data frame for each transformation so that you can see the result of each step.

```
# Change last colon to decimal point (period)
i$Date1 = gsub("(.*):(.*)(AM|PM)", "\\1\\.\\2\\3", i$Date)

# Parse date with milliseconds
i$NewDate = strptime(i$Date1, format="%b_%d_%Y_%I:%M:%OS%p")

i

                        Date                     Date1                 NewDate
1  Dec_28_2012_9:32:54:640PM Dec_28_2012_9:32:54.640PM 2012-12-28 21:32:54.640
2  Dec_28_2012_9:33:07:310PM Dec_28_2012_9:33:07.310PM 2012-12-28 21:33:07.310
3  Dec_28_2012_9:33:08:926PM Dec_28_2012_9:33:08.926PM 2012-12-28 21:33:08.926
...
13 Jan_1_2012_12:37:48:693PM Jan_1_2012_12:37:48.693PM 2012-01-01 12:37:48.693
14 Jan_1_2012_12:38:29:443PM Jan_1_2012_12:38:29.443PM 2012-01-01 12:38:29.443
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Is it that I missed the milliseconds? Just curious. Once I hear back from you, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I gave it a second thought and I don't know what the OP wants. In your answer you are ignoring `am/pm`  (see my comment) but I don't know what's the desired output really.

Comment: It looks like `%S:%OS` returns only whole seconds. Changing the colon to a period (in the data frame) and using just `%OS` seems to result in proper parsing.

Comment: Dear @eipi10 when I apply your solution I am getting all `NA` maybe due to my local configuration of my R session. How can I solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure. Did you copy and paste my code or type it in? If you typed it, check for typos. Also, try running the code in clean session with no packages loaded.

Comment: Dear @eipi10 I run the code in a clean session and the result is `NA` for `NewDate` maybe it could be due to my configuration of R is in Spanish. Any solution to this. Thanks

Comment: Try changing the period to a comma (that is, change `"\\1\\.\\2\\3"` to `"\\1\\,\\2\\3"`) and see if that works. You use `,` as the decimal marker in Ecuador, yes? The `.` as decimal marker might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 but using `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")` worked. I have my conf in Spanish. Thanks a lot of.